# stack-overflow tag in Pro Webmasters Meta

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

Any reason why the StackOverflow tag here in meta is called [stack-overflow](/questions/tagged/stack-overflow) instead of `stackoverflow` like in several other StackExchange sites and StackOverflow project itself?

Also, we have a [belongs-on-stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/belongs-on-stackoverflow) tag that makes me think [stack-overflow](/questions/tagged/stack-overflow) should be renamed `stackoverflow`.

Comment: See my comment on http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/591/please-retag-memcache-as-memcached as to why this may take a while to happen.